# Sort list of string based on number in string

Tags: python, list, sorting

For example I have list

```
my_list= ['image101.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image1.jpg']
```

and

```
my_list.sort()
```

gives me

```
['image1.jpg', 'image101.jpg', 'image2.jpg']
```

but I of course need

```
['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image101.jpg']
```

How it can be done?

Comment: `sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: int(re.search(r'\d+(?=\.)', x).group()))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to do this in the general case, I would try a natural sorting package like [natsort](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/natsort).

```
from natsort import natsorted
my_list = ['image101.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image1.jpg']
natsorted(my_list)
```

Returns:

```
['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image101.jpg']
```

You can install it using pip i.e. `pip install natsort`

Answer (score 20):

[`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) accepts optional `key` function. Each item is passed to the function, and the return value of the function is used to compare items instead of the original values.

```
>>> my_list= ['image101.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image1.jpg']
>>> my_list.sort(key=lambda x: int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, x))))
>>> my_list
['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image101.jpg']
```

---

[`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter), [`str.isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) were used to extract numbers:

```
>>> ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, 'image101.jpg'))
'101'
>>> int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, 'image101.jpg')))
101
```

- `''.join(..)` is not required in Python 2.x

Comment: Just wanted to mention this, it won't work if the file name is something like `image21_20160328.jpg`. The number it will extract is `2120160328`.

Comment: @JasonEstibeiro, You're right. In such case, need to capture all digits and convert them, using something like `lits(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', x)))`

Answer (score 9):

Use a regex to pull the number from the string and cast to int:

```
import  re
r = re.compile("\d+")
l = my_list= ['image101.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image1.jpg']
l.sort(key=lambda x: int(r.search(x).group()))
```

Or maybe use a more specific regex including the `.`:

```
import  re

r = re.compile("(\d+)\.")
l = my_list= ['image101.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image1.jpg']
l.sort(key=lambda x: int(r.search(x).group()))
```

Both give the same output for you example input:

```
['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image101.jpg']
```

If you are sure of the extension you can use a very specific regex:

```
 r = re.compile("(\d+)\.jpg$")
 l.sort(key=lambda x: int(r.search(x).group(1)))
```

Comment: for accuracy, you must use lookahead.

Comment: You need to convert the matched string to number. Otherwise, the result is different from what OP want. `['image1.jpg', 'image101.jpg', 'image2.jpg']
!= ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image101.jpg']`

Comment: @falsetru, yep, posted wrong version originally

Answer (score 4):

Actually you don't need any `regex` patern. You can parse easily like that.

```
>>> 'image101.jpg'[5:-4]
'101'
```

Solution:

```
>>> sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: int(x[5:-4]))
['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image101.jpg']
```